# Applescript Autotyper that let's me type out lines from a text file

Tags: applescript, automation

I'm trying to create a script that let's me either type out random phrases from within a list. OR takes this list from a text file and types it.

```
set theFile to "/Users/michaelelebiju/Desktop/Math Ninja 1.txt"
set fileHandle to open for access theFile
set storylines to paragraphs of (read fileHandle)
close access fileHandle

set numlines to count of storylines
set rn to (random number from 1 to numlines)
set reply to item rn of storylines
tell "System Events"
    activate application "Notes"
    keystroke reply
end tell
```

However, when I try to keystroke an entry, it returns:

error "Can’t make "PLOT TWIST" into type integer." number -1700 from "PLOT TWIST" to integer

Can anyone help me out here?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Key things: activate the app, get the cursor/insertion bar where it needs to be, then have System Events `tell process "appname"` to do the keystroke/key code.

These two examples should work if the specified app has a writable text area open and the insertion bar in it. Textedit should do this automatically if it has a window open but Notes has its own 'document' handling concepts. If you open a note, or click in the body area of a note (thus activating the insertion location there) then it should deposit the contents of your phrase there.

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit" to keystroke return & replies

tell application "Notes" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notes" to keystroke return & replies
```

There are likely other ways to do this but this generally works. I'll leave it to you to figure out the insertion location for any other apps.

Also, post an example of (and elaborate on) what you mean by comma-separated lists. There shouldn't be any issue that prevents you from also using something like that as your phrasebook.

**Original:**

Three things:

First, the proper way to access a random item from a list is with 'some':

```
set reply to some item of storylines
```

Second, an individual note has a folder location which needs to be referenced. You don't mention whether you are editing a note or creating one so here is how you might create a note (at Notes' root folder level).

```
set reply to some item of storylines
tell application "Notes" to make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:reply}
```

Finally, you shouldn't need to deal with access if you're only reading the text file (although maybe the OS requires it).

So to combine them all:

```
set theFile to "/Users/michaelelebiju/Desktop/Math Ninja 1.txt"
set storylines to paragraphs of (read theFile)

set reply to some item of storylines
tell application "Notes" to make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:reply}
```

I guess that it wouldn't hurt to add some information about editing a note instead of just creating it. Notes have a peculiar structure in that the first line —or name— seems to be plain text but the subsequent lines —or body— appear to be rendered HTML.

The easiest way (probably) to add to a note is to get its contents, append your additions and then set the note's contents. In attempting to be consistent with the app, I've just wrapped another random storyline in  tags and added that and a 
 onto a new line, and placed it all at the bottom of the most recent note. More complex text may require more complex treatment.

```
set theFile to "/Users/michaelelebiju/Desktop/Math Ninja 1.txt"
set storylines to paragraphs of (read theFile)

set reply to some item of storylines
tell application "Notes"
    set nl to last note
    
    set bl to body of nl    
    set bl to bl & linefeed & "<br><div>" & (some item of storylines) & "</div>"
    set body of nl to bl
    
end tell
```

Comment: Did you test the last _code block_ in your answer and if so what version of **macOS** are you running? I ask because in **macOS Catalina** is fails with e.g. `error "Notes got an error: Can’t make show id \"x-coredata://FB78651C-1EAE-4ACE-B93E-604CAC4EF439/ICNote/p41\" into type specifier." number -1700 from show id "x-coredata://FB78651C-1EAE-4ACE-B93E-604CAC4EF439/ICNote/p41" to specifier` with `body` been highlighted.

Comment: It shows what's returned from `set nl to last note` as e.g. `--> remove id "x-coredata://FB78651C-1EAE-4ACE-B93E-604CAC4EF439/ICNote/p41"` and I assume because of the leading `remove` it fails. Also without telling it which `folder`, it's accessing a _note_ in **Recently Deleted**, however, it still fails if I delete everything in **Recently Deleted** and or if I tell it to use the **Notes** _folder_.

Comment: Again with the non-descriptive and cryptic variable naming convention! They are not even necessary as it can be written simply as `tell application "Notes" to tell its last note of folder "Notes" to set its body to body of it & "<div>" & (some item of storylines) & "</div>"` and it actually works in **macOS Catalina** unlike the code in your answer. --- BTW Why `set reply to some item of storylines` if you are going to use `set bl to bl & linefeed & "<br><div>" & (some item of storylines) & "</div>"` instead of `set bl to bl & linefeed & "<br><div>" & reply & "</div>"`.

Comment: So because of the strangeness of errors I decided to reduce it to the minimum amount of _code_ and run it on a fresh clean install of **macOS Catalina** 10.15.7 and got a slightly different error but still failed with the _code_ shown in your answer. Here is a [screenshot of the error](https://i.imgur.com/A4B1zIQ.png).

Comment: Hi @Mockman~ Thank you very much for taking the time to type out that reply. Very much appreciated. The reason I had "activate application Notes" was because I was using notes to test. The main goal of what I'm trying to achieve is a line by line autotyper. Either by reading from a file (which you have helped me achieve) or by reading from a comma separated list. The biggest thing stopping me however is that, keystroke doesn't let me type out a list entry. Do you have any advice on getting around that?

Comment: Hi @MichaelElebiju, in general, an app and its text area must be active for the keystroke command to work. While your code includes the word 'activate', I don't think it works that way as system events doesn't activate the app. I'll edit the answer to include a couple of examples and try and clean up the whole thing later.